# Python connection issues

Tags: python, network-programming

So after learning a bit about python in a recent lecture I've decided to develop a script that will find a pc's ip address and from that ping within the user defined classful range.

It should then return a list of active addresses to a file.
Currently it's working but extremely slowly as it has a default timeout of 20  seconds per try.

I've tried using commands such as s.settimeout and s.setdefaulttimeout but when I set them it doesn't properly try the connection which results in saying every address but the first address is inactive as it goes though the connections in lighting speed. So heres the function dealing with it all.
ipsections is a list with the ip address octects within each section and z is a currently unused varable for future use.

```
def connect(ipSections,z):
  #socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  #s.settimeout(float(1))
  d=0
  for x in range (0,255):
      host = ipSections[0]+'.'+str(x+1)
      print(host)
      try:
          print(host)
          s.connect((host, 80))
          s.shutdown(2)
          s.close()
          s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
          f.write(host+'\n')
          #f.write('\n')
          print ('Y')
      except socket.error as e:
          d=d+1
          print('n')
  return d

d=connect(ipSections,z)
```

As I said it works fine but if I take out the comment for the default timeout it won't work.

Also quick note its I've written it in 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the socket creation code around like this:

```
def connect(ipSections,z):
  #socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  d=0
  for x in range (0,255):
      host = ipSections[0]+'.'+str(x+1)
      print(host)
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.settimeout(float(1))
      try:
          print(host)
          s.connect((host, 80))
          s.shutdown(2)
          s.close()
          f.write(host+'\n')
          #f.write('\n')
          print ('Y')
      except socket.error as e:
          d=d+1
          print('n')
  return d

d=connect(ipSections,z)
```

Otherwise after your first socket error you are doing operations on null socket descriptors

Comment: while that's accepted, it rattles though the whole address range and apparently can connect to each address, any thoughts?
What you've suggested makes sense but for some reason it doesn't seem to work :/